# Selenium webdriver python finding dynamic text from website

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

**Website**

[image: Website]

```
myList = ['Artik']
```

How can I check if content of myList is visible in website above?

```
<span class="ipo-TeamStack_TeamWrapper">Artik<span>
```

This is the webelement holding 'Artik' in the website.

My goal is to click the element containing 'Artik' and do some stuff after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Artik')]")
```

this return WebElement list contain 'Artik'.
parameter(like 'Artik') is case sensitive.

if you are convinced 'Artik' is only one,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Artik')]").click()
```

this will find WebElement with 'Artik' and click.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Artik')]").click()`  works well. <br/>What if I wanted to use text from myList[0] instead of 'Artik'?<br/>`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), myList[0])]').click()`<br/>Will cause error.

Comment: Sorry for bad editing skills above. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), myList[0])]').click()` does not cause error like I told above, but it does not click the correct element so it is not useful.

Comment: @Sane90 please refer to part 'String Formatting Operator' [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % myList[0]).click()`

Comment: Oh my, how did this not come to my mind at all. Thanks for the help. New here in the SO but gotta love how helpful fellow coders are.

Comment: @Sane90 if i helped to solve this problem, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Sane90 i am glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you find an element by xpath in selenium. I am using Firefox here but you can use Chrome as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

myList = ['Artik']
driver = webdriver.Firefox() # or .Chrome()
driver.get('www.theWebsite.com')

current = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="ipo-TeamStack_TeamWrapper"]').text
if current in myList:
    print('YAY')

driver.quit()
```